# Recurrence relationship for crawling a directory

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to write a recurrence relationship for problems that can be solved using recurrence.

As an example recurrent for finding the 3^4 (which is 3*3*3*3) can be written as:

```
f(b,e) = 
{
   1 if n == 0,
   b if n == 1,
   b * f(b, n-1) n > 1
}
```

Where we define f(b ,e) be the value of b ^ e (b raised to the power of e)

Similarly, if a directory and files within it is written is given below like such:

```
apple:
   green
   red
   yellow

orange:
   big
   small
cow:
   animal
```

How can I write a recurrence relation equation for it? I have written a  recursive program for it: https://github.com/pipa0979/PythonCode/blob/master/ProjectGoogle/Recursion/crawdirectory.py

I want to be able to write a recurrence equation to calculate the number of steps for crawling a directory.

Comment: I am a little confused by what you mean by "recurrence equation".  Do you mean expressing the behaviour using the language of mathematics?  Or perhaps an equation to calculate the number of steps?

Comment: What do you mean by a "recurrence relation equation" for "a directory and files within it"?

Comment: Yes, an equation to calculate the number of steps. @ Q the Platypus and @Gerry Myerson

Comment: Number of steps to do what? Please, edit the body of your question so that there is a clear, unambiguous question in it.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what "crawling a directory" means, but I can see one big difference between that and your $b^e$ example. Namely, $b^e$ just depends on two variables, whereas your directory can have a variable number of entries, each of which can have a variable number of files (and if your files can have subfiles, which can have subfiles, and so on, then it gets even worse).